# login form fails on 1st attempt on live server but works on second or third

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, authentication, logout

My login form works fine in Internet Explorer but in Chrome and Firefox it almost always fails on the first attempt. After reading just about every post on Stack Overflow without finding an answer I decided to post this. It always fails to log me in on the first attempt, it takes 2 or sometimes 3 attempts. I am including 2 parts of code, the first is my login.php and the second is my header.html where all the links are that should appear if the user is logged in.

I have tried a lot of things like flushing the dns, clearing my cache, uninstalling Chrome and reinstalling it, I tried my pages on 3 different computers, all with the same result.

I tested the query in phpmyadmin in the SQL form, and it always returns the UserID when I perform the Select query in my login.php file.

MYSQL is a Constant that points to my mysqli_connect file.

I am hoping this post will help others that may be having this problem.

Here is login.php

```
<?php
include ('includes/header.html');
include ('includes/config.inc.php');
$page_title = 'Login';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
require (MYSQL);
$trimmed = array_map('trim', $_POST);
    if (!empty($trimmed['Email']) && filter_var($trimmed['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)){
        $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['Email']);
    } else {
        $e = FALSE;
        echo '<p class="error">You forgot to enter your email address, or the email you entered is invalid.</p>';
    }
    if (!empty($trimmed['Pass']) && (preg_match ('/^\w{4,20}$/', $trimmed['Pass']))){
        $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['Pass']);
    } else {
        $p = FALSE;
        echo '<p class="error">You forgot to enter your password, or the password you entered is invalid.</p>';
    }
    if ($e && $p){
                $q = "SELECT UserID, Fname FROM users WHERE (Email='$e' AND Pass=SHA1('$p')) AND Active IS NULL";
                $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
                if (@mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1){
                    $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    mysqli_free_result($r);
                    mysqli_close($dbc);
                    $url =  BASE_URL . 'index.php';
                    ob_end_clean();
                    header("Location: $url");
                    exit();
                } else {
                    echo '<p class="error">Either the email address and password entered do not match those on file or you have not yet activated your account.</p>';
                }
            } else {
                echo '<p class="error">Please try again.</p>';
            }
mysqli_close($dbc);
} //end of submit conditional


?>
<div class="text">
<h1>Login</h1>
<p>Your browser must allow cookies in order to log in.</p>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<p><b>Email: <input type="text" name="Email" /></b></p>
<p><b>Password: <input type="password" name="Pass" /></b></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login!" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<? include ('includes/footer.html'); ?>
```

Here is header.html

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
<title><?php if (isset($page_title)){ echo $page_title; }?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php if (isset($description)){ echo $description; }?>">
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php if (isset($keywords)){echo $keywords; }?>">
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#menu li").hover(function(){
        $(this).children(":hidden").slideDown();

    },function(){
        $(this).parent().find("ul").slideUp();

    });

});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="logo">
<img src="images/links.jpg" border="0" alt="Links">
</div>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.example.com">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    <ul>
                <li class="sub"><a href="how_it_works.php">How It Works</a></li>
                <li class="sub"><a href="link_placement.php">Link Placement</a></li>
                <li class="sub"><a href="verifying_your_links.php">Verifying Links</a></li>
                <li class="sub"><a href="link_partners.php">Link Partners</a></li>
                <li class="sub"><a href="terms.php">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>

    <li><a href="#">Account Management</a>
            <ul>

                <?php
                    if (isset($_SESSION['UserID'])){
                        echo '<li class="sub"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>';
                        echo '<li class="sub"><a href="add_url.php?id=' . $_SESSION['UserID'] . '">Add Your Url</a></li>';
                        echo '<li class="sub"><a href="directory.php">Directory of Sites</a></li>';
                        echo '<li class="sub"><a href="view_sites.php?id=' . $_SESSION['UserID'] . '">View/Edit Urls</a></li>';
                        echo '<li class="sub"><a href="edit_account.php?id=' . $_SESSION['UserID'] . '">Edit Account</a></li>';
                        echo '<li class="sub"><a href="change_password.php">Change Password</a></li>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<li class="sub"><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>';
                        echo '<li class="sub"><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>';
                    } 
                    ?>
                <li class="sub"><a href="forgot_password.php">Forgot Password</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
    <li><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>


</ul>
<div align="center" id="sidebar">
<?php include('includes/ads.php'); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was running into the same issue, and after searching for "why header() redirect doesn't work" as suggested by @Toly, I found a couple of posts that mentioned you should check if the `SESSION` has already been started before calling `session_start()`. I also relocated my `header()` from the top of the page to inside my code block that handles if the login is successful.

Answer (score 1):

I bet that your header.html will display the correct links after the first login attempt (with correct credentials) after a page refresh, without doing the authorization again.

Is that right?

Well, if yes, you have manage to reach a little loop between $_SESSION initiation (session_start() function), output caching mechanism (ob_start() function) and header redirection (header("Location") function)

Your search query should be 'why header() redirection doesn't work', and you will find your answer instantly - because there was something output to the browser before headers.

What happens, most likely, is that your authorization works, you set $_SESSION variable, but do not get a redirection. After you try to see the page again - surprise, you are already authorized. Don't need any other login attempts as well.

Comment: Oh, and IE might ignore some of those rules. So, that's why it works in IE.

Comment: no, my header.html file will not display the correct links after the first login attempt.

Comment: reload the page after your first login attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to clean up your code and see what happens.
Put your code to check user login details at the top of your page,
if error happens, save it in a variable and then display it, otherwise redirect user.

### Note: code not tested

```
<?php
  include( "includes/config.inc.php" );
  if ( strtolower( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) === "post" && ( isset( $_POST["Email"], $_POST["Pass"] ) ) ) {
    session_start();
    $email  = filter_var( trim( $_POST["Email"] ), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
    $pass   = preg_match( '/^\w{4,20}$/', trim( $_POST["Pass"] ) ) ? trim( $_POST["Pass"] ) : false;

    if ( $email ) {
      if ( $pass ) {
        $email  = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc, $email );
        $pass   = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc, $pass );

        $query  = "SELECT UserID, Fname FROM users WHERE ( Email = '$e' AND Pass = SHA1('$p') ) AND Active IS NULL";
        $result = mysqli_query( $dbc, $query );
        if ( $result ) {
          if ( (int)mysqli_num_rows( $result ) === 1 ) {
            $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC );
            mysqli_free_result( $result );
            mysqli_close( $dbc );
            header( "Location: ".BASE_URL."index.php" );
            exit();
          }
          else {
            $error  = 'Either the email address and password entered do not match those on file or you have not yet activated your account.';
          }
        }
        else {
          $error  = 'Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: '. mysqli_error( $dbc );
        }
      }
      else {
        $error  = 'You forgot to enter your password, or the password you entered is invalid.';
      }
    }
    else {
      $error  = 'You forgot to enter your email address, or the email you entered is invalid.';
    }
  }

  mysqli_close( $dbc );

  $page_title = "Login"; // put this, just before including "header.html", so you can use it in your header file
  include( "includes/header.html" );
  // A
?>
<div class="text">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <p>Your browser must allow cookies in order to log in.</p>
  <?php
    if ( isset( $error ) ) {
      echo '<p class="error">'.$error.'</p>';
    }
  ?>
  <form action="login.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <p><b>Email: <input type="text" name="Email" /></b></p>
      <p><b>Password: <input type="password" name="Pass" /></b></p>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login!" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<?php
  include( "includes/footer.html" );
?>
```

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, because I don't get any kind of validation error, while cleaning up the code might be a good idea programming wise, it won't fix the main problem in my opinion.